# D3 with crossfilter becomes very slow large datasets

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, d3.js, crossfilter

I have a visualization similar to the crossfilter example, except that the crossfilter selection dynamically updates a timeline. The code works well with around 100 elements. I tested the code with close to 5000 elements and it became very slow when applying/changing the brush to filter the dimensions. I was wondering where the performance issue was and how to fix it. The timeline with around 5000 svg rects rendered well. The crossfilter histograms were very slorw (not creating the histogram, but when resizing and applying brush) when applying and resizing the brush. I even disabled the timeline from updating after the brush changes and that did not help performance. I am generating the crossfilter histograms using the svg path method similar to that in the crossfilter example.I am not sure why drawing the brush is taking so long.

Could it be related to the crossfilter? A note about the data: while there are only a few thousand elements of data in the crossfilter, the elements are very large (contain around a hundred or so attributes). not sure if that contributes to the problem.

Thanks
a

Comment: Which browser/operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually performance problems such as you're describing will be caused by the browser rendering the generated SVG rather than the actual processing of the data in Javascript. One thing you could try is to use HTML canvas instead of SVG. Note that converting your code to do so will not be a trivial process however.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried out my code without rendering the 5000 element timeline and the performance issue went away. Any tips or resources you recommend for converting to canvas? will it require a complete code rewrite?

Comment: There's an example with d3 [here](http://bl.ocks.org/1276463). It shouldn't require a complete rewrite, but probably quite substantial changes.

Comment: I agree with Lars that canvas could really help out here if you need to render thousands of elements.  Depending on the details of your visualization though, there might be a way to guide the user to filter down the dataset further before rendering the timeline, a narrower window of time perhaps?  Or maybe some form of aggregation? Such a strategy worked well for me on a previous d3 timeline I built, where only a hundred or so elements are rendered at any given time of a much larger few hundred thousand element dataset.